# Android Emulator did not show other available WIFI signal

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-emulator, adb

I tried to connect my other local wifi to android emulator but it doesn't show any wifi signal

Comment: Emulator is not a real device, so please keep it in  mind, it won't show you that because it doesn't have any real hardware it's just a software.

Comment: The emulator doesn't have wifi.  It gets its internet via tunneling over to the host PC (your laptop).  As such it can't change networks or get a list of available ones.

Answer (score 0):

Wifi is not available on the emulator if you are using below of API level 25.

For More Information: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator.html#wifi

Comment: thanks for your  information...  but I have to test my application by connecting another wifi network for eg(my app is based on signal capturing feature by connecting particular signal receiver that device pull the data to my application) give me some better idea to archive EXCEPT CONNECTING VIA USB DEBUGGING